# How do I recreate the default 2D camera in my Unity project

Tags: unity, 2d, camera

I was using Unity but my PC shut down suddenly; when I reopened my project, all my GameObjects, including my camera, had disappeared. The good thing is that I created prefabs of all of them (except the camera).

So now I tried making a GameObject with a camera component but it doesn't seem to work like the original: I can't seem to readjust the size of the camera and it suddenly has diagonals running from edge to edge. I couldn't find a solution online and I am wondering if there is a way to remake the original camera.

Comment: If you found the answer it should be posted as an Answer post below, not appended to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the “GameObject” drop down menu, then select Camera and it will create the Camera object in the Hierarchy. If you want to make it the main camera in your scene then in the Inspector click on the “Tag” drop down box and select “Main Camera”. Save your changes.

Comment: You may want to mention how to change between perspective and orthographic modes too.